# Universal Property of Products in $A$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, direct-sum, direct-product

I am studying some notes in which the second Universal Property of Products in $A$-modules is defined as following:

> Given an $A$-modules family $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$, for all test $A$-module $T$ we have a canonical isomorphism:
>
> $$ \Pi_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}_A(M_i,T)=\operatorname{Hom}_A(\oplus_{i\in I}M_i,T)\\
> (\psi_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto ((m_i)_{i\in I}\to \sum _{i\in I}\psi_i(m_i)).$$

My question, maybe trivial (but I am stuck on that...), is the following: suppose that $I$ is infinite and $\psi_i$ non-zero are infinite. How to choose the subfamily $(m_i)\in \oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ to construct the image of the isomorphism once there are infinites subfamilies $(m_i)\in \oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ (i.e., with almost $m_i=0$)?

Many thanks in advance for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na'omi kindly invited me to post the following comment as an answer.

Here is a slightly more explicit statement of the universal property in question:

Given an $A$-modules family $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$, for all test $A$-module $T$ we have a canonical isomorphism: 
$$
\Phi:\prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_A(M_i,T)\to\text{Hom}_A\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i,T\right)
$$ 
defined by 
$$
(\Phi((\psi_i)_{i\in I}))((m_i)_{i\in I})=\sum _{i\in I}\psi_i(m_i).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for help and return.

Answer (score 1):

The subtlety is that in $(m_i)_{i \in I} \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ we have $m_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$ by construction of the direct sum. That's why the sum $\sum_{i \in I} \psi_i(m_i)$ is well-defined: almost every term is $0$.

Comment: Hello. First of all, many thanks for attention. Maybe I did not explain very well. My doubt is at definition of the isomorphism. Given $I $ infinite, there is infinite many subsets that one can take $m_i\neq0$, so how can I choose one of them to construct the image of $(\psi_i)_{i\in I} $? Maybe it is trivial... I am stucked at here. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Na'omi - The $m_i$ are bound variables.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard, sorry, could you explain a little bit more, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Na'omi - You're welcome! Please let me know if this variant looks clearer to you: Given an $A$-modules family $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$, for all test $A$-module $T$ we have a canonical isomorphism: $$\Phi:\prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_A(M_i,T)\to\text{Hom}_A\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i,T\right)$$ defined by $$(\Phi((\psi_i)_{i\in I}))((m_i)_{i\in I})=\sum _{i\in I}\psi_i(m_i).$$

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard, yes...! Thank you so much. I do not know if my language is OK, but I would say that my doubty about "what subset I choose to construct the image" is, in fact, answered as "all of them", because they are the elements of the dominium on the image... You clarified a lot, many thanks. If you consider post as an answer, I'll upvote the answer of QiZhu and accepted yours. Best regards.